# Не обрабатывается условие else

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Не обрабатывается условие else(
Написано вроде все верно, но письмо, если человек впервые заполнил Google Форму и оставил адрес электронной почты, не приходит

```
     function sendEmailToClient2() {
      
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      
      //Лист текущей таблицы с именем "List", в который загружаются ответы из формы, записан в переменную:
      var listAnswers = ss.getSheetByName('List'); 
      
      //Получен email клиента из ячейки с адресом: последняя строка, 6 ряд, - и записан в переменную:
      var clientEmail = listAnswers.getRange(listAnswers.getLastRow(),6).getValue();
    
      var clientEmails = listAnswers
      .getRange(2,6,listAnswers.getLastRow()-2)
      .getValues().flat();
    
        if(clientEmails.includes(clientEmail)) {
    
          var body = 
          'S2';
          // other
//else не обрабатывается
        } else {
      
        var body = 
          'S1';
          // new
        }
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(clientEmail, "",'',{htmlBody: body}); 
      }
```

Comment: Потому что `clientEmails.includes(clientEmail)` возвращает true, другого не дано

Comment: @SwaD как в этом случае написать код? Просто мне необходимо, чтобы, если человек заполнил форму первый раз, ему приходило письмо с body = "S1", а если последующие, то body = "S2"

Comment: А как вы определяете, первый раз он заполнил или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что не надо отнимать от последней строки 2